# How to find duplicates?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, search

I am facing a basic problem: I do not know whether I am being silly or not, but often when I look at some questions, I feel that I have seen that before (if they have special structures like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817025/does-int-0-int-0-int-0-mathstrut-dx-dx-dx)) on Math.SE but, have forgotten the name of the question entirely (and it is not possible to check all questions under a tag). So is there any special trick that more experienced users use to find duplicates?

Comment: I have doubts whether this will help with the specific question you linked, but there were some discussions about [meta-tag:search] on meta. For example, you could have a look at the following questions (and some links given there in comments or answers):
[How do you search for duplicates?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258),
[How do you search for specific questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5048),
[What is the best way to search for a math equation on the internet?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12993) or ...

Comment: ... [How to search math terms/notations accurately and efficiently? Could some experienced users summarize some tips here?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21900)  In the specific case you link, you perhaps might ask the user who posted a link to a duplicate in a comment how they found it.

Comment: Interestingly, ["int 0 int 0 int 0" site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22int+0+int+0+int+0%22+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) only returns the question you linked. (I hoped it might catch at least some of the other questions linked to that one.) Using built-in-search with the query ["\int_0^{\int_0"](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22\int_0^{\int_0%22) returned [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1608525) which is to some extent similar.

Comment: I have had limited success searching for duplicates. Also, sometimes there are answers that do address the new question but are not really duplicates but are close. Not sure what to do with that.